# Creating Windows Phone page with XSLT (xml and xaml syntax )

Tags: xml, xaml, xslt, windows-phone

I have to create Windows Phone Page from XML with XSLT. This is how looks first lines in windows phone page:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:RssPhoneApp_ViewModels="clr-namespace:RssPhoneApp.ViewModels" 
x:Class="RssPhoneApp.MainPage"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">
```

And I don't know how to manage with **"phone"** prefix in phone:PhoneApplicationPage and **xmlns** attribute. I don't have any idea how this should works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest just reading up on XSL as there is a ton of developer resources out there. [Here is an article that discusses how to deal with namespaces in XSL](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/04/04/trxml/index.html).

> Simply declare and use the namespace you need in your stylesheet and the XSLT processor will
>
> - put that namespace declaration in the start-tag of the result document's document element, and
> - put the prefix for that namespace in the tags for any result tree elements from that namespace.